# Logging shell command executed by all users on Linux server

Tags: linux, security, shell, audit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to log every linux command to a logserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/201221/how-to-log-every-linux-command-to-a-logserver)

I want to log the commands executed by all users on the server. Is there any better way than using `script` command?

Comment: Why are you looking to record all commands?

Answer (score 0):

A possible application to do this is rootsh. see: http://sourceforge.net/projects/rootsh/

Be careful though, you will be capturing all sorts of passwords, confidential data and other things that need to be stored in the highest security you have available. Think of what could happen if this information was captured. Also, depending on the number of users on your system there could be a lot of data.

Answer (score -2):

That should be contained under `history` for each of the users or under /home/$username/.bash_history where $username is the name of the actual user, of course if the user home directory is not under home that it will be like /path/to/homedir/.bash_history

Comment: history -c ; export HISTFILE=/dev/null; do stuff; exit. The information only gets written to $HISTFILE when the user exits cleanly.